# crash on calling addPersistentStoreWithType with an invalid URL - File at path does not appear to be a SQLite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

i need to handle core data errors when a corrupt/non-sqlite is passed to

```
- (NSPersistentStore *)addPersistentStoreWithType:(NSString *)storeType configuration:(NSString *)configuration URL:(NSURL *)storeURL options:(NSDictionary *)options error:(NSError **)error
```

it causes a crash. The crash clearly describes the error

*Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 259.)" UserInfo=0xb925300 {NSUnderlyingException=File at path does not appear to be a SQLite database:*

in the assumption that a **nil** value will be returned in such cases i handled it such a way

```
if (![storeCoordeinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
};
```

but it still crashes. What's the proper way to handle this error in such cases. ?

Answer (score 2):

Use try-catch block. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html at the bottom of page

```
BOOL isValidDatabaseFile = YES;
@try
{
if (![storeCoordeinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
};
}
@catch(NSException *ex)
{
    isValidDatabaseFile = NO;
}
@finally
{
}
```

then check `isValidDatabaseFile`

Comment: Agreed. That method should just return an error in this case, but it doesn't. Catching the exception is the only reasonable alternative.

Comment: is there any way that i can check if the received file (an NSData response being saved on to a file) is SQLite database compatiable. So it will be much easier to handle. In the above case i can't properly handle the flow even if the exception is catched